# KernelBrowser adding params to body POST request

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test an endpoint of my Api with phpunit and the symfony WebTestCase object. I have to send a POST request with the KernelBrowser but I can't figure it out how to add parameters to the body of the request. My request work fine on postman.

I've tried this
`$client->request('POST', '/url', ['param1' =>'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']);`

It's not working.

I've tried this
`$client->request('POST', '/url', [], [], [], '{param1: value, param2: value}');`

It doesn't work,
I can't use the `$client->submitForm()` method because the form is send by another app.

Maybe it came from my Api endpoint because I'm using $_POST variable ?:

```
$res = false;
if(count($_POST) === 2){
  $user = $this->userrepo->findByName($_POST['value1']);
  if($user){
    if($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user[0], $_POST['value2'])){
      $res = true;   
    }
  }
}
return new Response($this->serializer->serialize(['isChecked' => $res], 'json'));
```

My test method has never passed the first if statement,
here my test method:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/url', ['value1' => 'value1', 'value2' => 'value2']);
$this->assertStringContainsString('{"isChecked":true}', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Here the POST request I'm trying to send:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000/url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--form 'value1=value1' \
--form 'value2=value2'
```

Comment: for debugging purposes, you could just output `$_POST` in your controller to see if it contains the values you send in your test. And I assume you're right in your theory it might not contain the values at all.

Comment: I will try with the symfony http request object, but in the documentation their is nothing about this kind of problem so I think I will report a bug

Comment: I believe requests are given to the kernel directly and there is no web server started or something. Hence, there would be work involved to actually put the data into the POST global.

Comment: This sound pretty right, I'm just going to do things in a different way

Comment: okay so I output the `$_POST`  and it's an empty array, I also output `$req->request->all()` ($req is the request object of the http foundation component). It's also empty, so I 'm going to mock this method

Answer (score 1):

Symfony's test client dispatches the request internally. The global `$_POST` variable will always be empty. You should use the `Request` object in the controller to access the parameters. The attribute `request` contains the post data.

```
public function myAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $postParameters = $request->request;

    $res = false;
    if ($postParameters->count() === 2) {
        $user = $this->userrepo->findByName($postParameters->get('value1'));
        if ($user) {
            if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user[0], $postParameters->get('value2'))) {
                $res = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Response($this->serializer->serialize(['isChecked' => $res], 'json'));
}
```

Regarding the different variations of your test call, this one should work with the action above.

```
$client->request('POST', '/url', ['value1' => 'value1', 'value2' => 'value2']);
```